# How to modify MariaDB SQL Error Log plugin system variables?

Tags: mariadb

I just installed this plugin to monitor SQL errors:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-error-log-plugin/

but I can't for the life of me find anything on how to modify the default system variables for that error log plugin, and where.

Anyone?!

Comment: You mean [`SET`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set/)?

Comment: Set, modify, etc. They are all coming up as read only variables somehow if I use SET and that doesn't change them at all.

Comment: You can check https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#setting-server-system-variables on how to set the non-dynamic system variables.

Comment: Yeah, none of that worked. I set them in my.cnf, I used SET, nothing takes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify error plugin log variables via SQL statements. They are either read-only and/or they need to be specified at startup (see [source code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.8/plugin/sql_errlog/sql_errlog.c#L49)).

So you have to pass these values either to mariadbd/mysqld or you have to specify these in your configuration file.

Example in /etc/my.cnf:

```
[server]
sql-error-log-filename=foo.log
sql-error-log-rotate=ON
```

restart server and check the values

```
MariaDB [test]> show variables like 'sql_error%';
+--------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name            | Value   |
+--------------------------+---------+
| sql_error_log_filename   | foo.log |
| sql_error_log_rate       | 1       |
| sql_error_log_rotate     | ON      |
| sql_error_log_rotations  | 9       |
| sql_error_log_size_limit | 1000000 |
+--------------------------+---------+
```